# error says is not a function but it is a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have some code in a React component AddProject that looks like this.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./addproject.css";
import UserContext from "../../UserContext";
import saveProject from '../../features/saveProject';

function AddProject() {

    const handleSaveProject = () => {

        const projectData = {

        [userEmail]: {
            clientName: clientName,
            clientEmail: clientEmail,
            stages: stages,
        }
    }

    console.log(userEmail, projectData);

    saveProject(projectData)
//etc
```

I alsa have another component/method saveProject that I want to pass some props to and make a post request with Axios.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const saveProject = (projectData) => {

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        axios

            .post("[http://localhost:4000/users](http://localhost:4000/users)", projectData)
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));

    };

    return (null);
};

export default saveProject;
```

I keep getting this error telling me it isn't a function. I've tried changing the import statement to {saveProject} and doing export const instead, but that didn't help. ChatGPT can't figure it out either. Any ideas?

```
2AddProject.jsx:86 Uncaught TypeError: _features_saveProject__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...) is not a function
at handleSaveProject (AddProject.jsx:86:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
```

Comment: _"ChatGPT can't figure it out either"_ - I don't want to live on this planet anymore...

Comment: Have you re-run WebPack to regenerate the executed JS? Please share the details of how you build your project. Can you reproduce it in Stackblitz?

Comment: silly question, but: are you _sure_ that's the right import location, as opposed to a file that exists but isn't the file you're showing in your second code block?

Comment: Please share your webpack configuration

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought you may be right but I checked really close and it's right. AddProject is in src/components/AddProject/AddProject.js and the other file is src/features/saveProject.js

Import statement for AddProject is: import saveProject from '../../features/saveProject'

I mistakenly made it lowercase against convention, but it does match with how it's exported and the file name. Thank you though.

Comment: @Dai Yes I've restarted the server multiple times. This is the config.
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Comment: Restarting a server won't necessarily force WebPack to perform a _clean_ rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I somehow didn't save or did or something, but it wasn't being exported. Restarting the server didn't help, but when I restarted my computer the error showed for some reason. Thank you everyonev